# how to copy a file to all desktop folders in the C: Users directory using powershell script

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I am trying to copy a file to all desktop folders in the C: Users directory using a powershell script. I am able to do this for individual folders if putting the folder name in the script. When using the wild card, I receive the illegal character error and it doesn't work. The script is below; Any suggestions?

```
Copy-Item -Path "\\Server IP\C$\Users\Default\Desktop\file.url" -Destination "\\Server IP\c$\Users\*\Desktop" -Force
```

Comment: There is no wildcard in the script you provided.

Comment: try to evaluate the part in quotes >>> `-Destination "\Server IP\c$\Users*\Desktop"`. you will note that it has the wildcard directly attached to `Users` ... and that is not where the user profile dirs will be. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you put that command in a foreach loop like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "\Server IP\c$\Users" -Directory | foreach {

    Copy-Item -Path "\Server IP\C$\Users\Default\Desktop\file.url" -Destination "\Server IP\c$\Users\$_.Name\Desktop" -Force

}
```

Comment: The UNC paths should start with a double backslash. Also, you would want to exclude destination `\\Server IP\c$\Users\Public`